# JavaScript functions help needed

Tags: javascript, function

I'm practicing JavaScript and have come up with a little project ... get the diameters of various bodies in our solar system when I click on corresponding buttons.

I've been able to do this, but not very efficiently. Currently, the only way my code works is with 11 functions. I also have two objects (one for the body names and the other for the body diameters).

Any feedback to make my code more efficient is very welcome. Thank you! :-)

```js
//JavaScript

var bodyName = {   
 su:"the Sun",
 me:"Mercury",
 ve:"Venus",
 ea:"Earth",
 mo:"the Moon",
 ma:"Mars",
 ju:"Jupiter",
 sa:"Saturn",
 ur:"Uranus",
 ne:"Neptune",
 pl:"Pluto"
 };

var bodyDiam = {
 su:864576,
 me:3032,
 ve:7521,
 ea:7918,
 mo:2159,
 ma:4212,
 ju:86881,
 sa:72367,
 ur:31518,
 ne:30599,
 pl:1475
};

function suInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.su;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.su;
}

function meInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.me;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.me;
}

function veInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.ve;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.ve;
}

function eaInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.ea;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.ea;
}

function moInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.mo;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.mo;
}

function maInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.ma;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.ma;
}

function juInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.ju;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.ju;
}

function saInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.sa;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.sa;
}

function urInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.ur;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.ur;
}

function neInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.ne;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.ne;
}

function plInfo() {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName.pl;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam.pl;
}
```

```css
<!--CSS-->

p {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 0.25em 0.5em 0;
  background-color: #393;
}

.result {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e80;
}
```

```html
<!--html-->

<!--buttons-->

<button type="button" class="button" id="suButton" onclick="suInfo()">Sun</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="meButton" onclick="meInfo()">Mercury</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="veButton" onclick="veInfo()">Venus</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="eaButton" onclick="eaInfo()">Earth</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="moButton" onclick="moInfo()">Moon</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="maButton" onclick="maInfo()">Mars</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="juButton" onclick="juInfo()">Jupiter</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="saButton" onclick="saInfo()">Saturn</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="urButton" onclick="urInfo()">Uranus</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="neButton" onclick="neInfo()">Neptune</button>
<button type="button" class="button" id="plButton" onclick="plInfo()">Pluto</button>

<!--Information Display-->

<p>The diameter of <span class="result" id="bodyNameDisplay">this body</span> is <span class="result" id="bodyDiamDisplay">this many</span> miles.</p>
```

Comment: @JoshBeam in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *unclear what you're asking*, *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @JoshBeam No, it's too broad. That's why you should close it. Whether it fits somewhere else is irrelevant. Besides, it needs some serious work before it's a good question over there.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using seperate functions for each button, you can pass an argument to the functions

```
function info(planet) {
    document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerText = bodyName[planet];
    document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerText = bodyDiam[planet];
}
```

Then in the button, you can pass the argument onclick

`<button type="button" class="button" id="plButton" onclick="info('pl')">Pluto</button>`

If you also want to generate the buttons automatically, you can use javascript for that as well:

html:

```
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

js:

```
var buttonsContainer = document.body.getElementById("buttons");
for(var planetId in bodyName){ // Loop over every planet
    var button = document.createElement("button"); // Creates <button></button>
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "info('"+planetId+"')") // Add onclick=info('id');
    button.innerText = bodyName[planetId] // Add the text inside <button>PlanetName</button>
    button.classList.add("button"); // Add the class="button" class
    button.setAttribute("id", planetId+"Button"); // Add the id="idButton"
    button.setAttribute("type", "button"); // Add the type="button"
    buttonsContainer.appendChild(button); // Add the button to the div of buttons
}
```

Example:

```js
//JavaScript

var bodyName = {   
 su:"the Sun",
 me:"Mercury",
 ve:"Venus",
 ea:"Earth",
 mo:"the Moon",
 ma:"Mars",
 ju:"Jupiter",
 sa:"Saturn",
 ur:"Uranus",
 ne:"Neptune",
 pl:"Pluto"
 };

var bodyDiam = {
 su:864576,
 me:3032,
 ve:7521,
 ea:7918,
 mo:2159,
 ma:4212,
 ju:86881,
 sa:72367,
 ur:31518,
 ne:30599,
 pl:1475
};

function info(planet) {
  document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerText = bodyName[planet];
  document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerText = bodyDiam[planet];
}



var buttonsContainer = document.getElementById("buttons");
for(var planetId in bodyName){ // Loop over every planet
  var button = document.createElement("button"); // Creates <button></button>
  button.setAttribute("onclick", "info('"+planetId+"')") // Add onclick=info(id);
  button.innerText = bodyName[planetId] // Add the text inside <button>PlanetName</button>
  button.classList.add("button"); // Add the class="button" class
  button.setAttribute("id", planetId+"Button"); // Add the id="idButton"
  button.setAttribute("type", "button"); // Add the type="button"
  buttonsContainer.appendChild(button); // Add the button to the div of buttions
}
```

```css
p {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 0.25em 0.5em 0;
  background-color: #393;
}

.result {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e80;
}
```

```html
<!--html-->

<!--buttons-->

<div id="buttons"></div>

<!--Information Display-->

<p>The diameter of <span class="result" id="bodyNameDisplay">this body</span> is <span class="result" id="bodyDiamDisplay">this many</span> miles.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the planet identifier as an argument to the `info()` function:

```
function info(id) {
    document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodyName[id];
    document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodyDiam[id];
}
```

This way one function is enough.
The HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="button" id="suButton" onclick="info('su')">Sun</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the two sets of details into one array of objects that contain the details for that body.This way you can access all the information in a single function and simply pass a variable to the function that will access the index of the object within the array and return the name and diameter from a single object.

```js
//JavaScript

var bodies = [
  {name:"the Sun", "diameter": 864576},
  {name:"Mercury", diameter: 3032},
  {name:"Venus", diameter: 7521},
  {name:"Earth", diameter: 7918},
  {name:"the Moon", diameter: 2159},
  {name:"Mars", diameter: 4212},
  {name:"Jupiter", diameter: 86881},
  {name:"Saturn", diameter: 72367},
  {name:"Uranus", diameter: 31518},
  {name:"Neptune", diameter: 30599},
  {name:"Pluto", diameter: 1475},
];

function setInfo(index) {
 document.getElementById("bodyNameDisplay").innerHTML = bodies[index].name;
 document.getElementById("bodyDiamDisplay").innerHTML = bodies[index].diameter;
}
```

```css
<!--CSS-->

p {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 0.25em 0.5em 0;
  background-color: #393;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e80;
}
```

```html
<!--html-->

<!--buttons-->

<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(0)">Sun</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(1)">Mercury</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(2)">Venus</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(3)">Earth</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(4)">Moon</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(5)">Mars</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(6)">Jupiter</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(7)">Saturn</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(8)">Uranus</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(9)">Neptune</button>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setInfo(10)">Pluto</button>

<!--Information Display-->

<p>The diameter of <span class="result" id="bodyNameDisplay">this body</span> is <span class="result" id="bodyDiamDisplay">this many</span> miles.</p>
```